# Characteristics of Transistor

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, temperature

What changes when we replace a bipolar junction transistor with another one of same type in the a circuit?

Comment: What changes? The time of day changes because the change cannot be done instantly.

Comment: If swapping exact part numbers there can be a tiny difference in the beta (gain) of the same transistor type. This is usually over come by using feed back loops.

Answer (score 1):

Every parameter will change based on the production variation / spread.

[image]

*Figure 1. 2N2222 datasheet extract showing parameter limits.*

A good design will be tolerant of component variation and will work within the design specification for variation in parameters of all components, active and passive. This is part of the art of electronics design.

Answer (score 0):

In the real world it is **impossible** to find **identical** transistors. Only in a circuit simulator will you find identical transistors.

You can buy "matched" transistors or even several transistors in one housing on the same chip die. But even then, their parameters will vary between all of them. They will vary less than non-matched transistors though.

If you cannot find a difference between two transistors then you're not measuring accurately enough. In practice you have to ask yourself: which parameters matter to my circuit and how much variation is acceptable?

Often by choosing the right circuit topology the variations between transistors becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you install two identical transistors in a circuit, and *look* at the circuit, the HEAT from your *face* will cause an imbalance in the emitter-base voltages. This imbalance will be 500 microvolts or more, if you remain still and let your body/face continue to radiate heat onto the 2 transistors for a few minutes. The black plastic causes big time delays in thermal flows, given the end point of the heat is the silicon die + metal mounting plate inside the plastic, and lots of heat must flow thru the epoxy plastic and reach the  "transistor".